# Magento Fatal error about load()

Tags: php, xml, magento, load

here is my problem, can anyone please show me the mistake? I tried as much as I can but still couldnt find the mistake...Hope to fix it because it has already taken me two days to face the problem.... It's terrible...
Call to a member function load() on a non-object in...
my config.xml
`<global>
    <models>
    <appointment>
        <class>Ltsport_Appointment_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>appointment_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </appointment>
    <appointment_mysql4>
    <class>Ltsport_Appointment_Model_Mysql4</class>
    <entities>
        <apptshow>
            <table>appt_master</table>
        </apptshow>
    </entities>
    </appointment_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <appointment_write>
            <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </appointment_write>
        <appointment_read>
            <connection>
               <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </appointment_read>

        <appt_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Ltsport_Appointment</module>
                <class>Ltsport_Appointment_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </appt_setup>
    </resources>
  </global>`
my IndexController.php

```
<?php 
class Ltsport_Appointment_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
   public function indexAction(){
        echo "Index!";
   }
    public function setupAction(){
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $apptshow = Mage::getModel('appointment/apptshow');
        $apptshow->load($params['id']);
        $data = $apptshow->getData();
        var_dump($data);
   }
}
?>`
```

Apptshow.php at \Model

```
<?php

class Ltsport_Appointment_Model_Mysql4_Apptshow extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('appointment/apptshow');
}
}
?>
```

Apptshow.php at \Model\Mysql4\

```
<?php

class Ltsport_Appointment_Model_Mysql4_Apptshow extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('appointment/apptshow');
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apptshow.php at \Model\Mysql4\ should be a resource model extending `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract`.

```
class Ltsport_Appointment_Model_Mysql4_Apptshow extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('appointment/apptshow', 'id');
    }
}
```

Also note that `Mysql4` was deprecated after Magento CE 1.6.

Comment: Thx, I updated the codes. I find that the problem is 
$apptshow = Mage::getModel('appt/apptshow');
Code like this doesnt work with my module and model.... Do you know why?